# Selectively remove Chrome browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, browser-history

Is it possible to selectively remove items from Google Chrome browsing history? I have a website from my history that wants to be the default everytime I start a search with a specific letter, but I often reference my history to re-find things.

So I would like to remove all history from, say, www.pythonismyfavoritest.com without removing everything; is that possible?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a bad redirect (good URL that chrome was redirecting to a bad one) that I thought was in my history. It was actually in a cookie. Deleting the cookies for the site fixed my problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try searching `www.pythonismyfavoritest.com` in the search bar in `chrome://history/` and then remove each item by clicking the check box in the left and then hitting the "remove selected items" button.

The chrome history api works with url such `chrome://history/#q=hello&p=0`

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31568408/Capture.PNG]

Comment: Thanks! That did work though it's a bit tedious for more than a few matches.

Comment: @DylanHettinger You can select multiple consecutive matches by selecting the first match, holding the shift button and selecting the last match. _(I just noticed)_

Comment: Hey, I usually don't like to promote software, but I'll make an exception. There is an extension called  "Better History"( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb?hl=en ), that could be defined as chrome history on steroids. It has some nice features that I frequently use.

Comment: It's also possible to build Chrome extensions that selectively remove history using the [`chrome.history`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/) API.

Answer (score 19):

Here's something I wrote in JavaScript. It works through the Console Debugger. I tried using it in a bookmark but I get no response from the page.

** **// UPDATE (07.28.15)**
I added a shorter approach provided by @Denis Gorbachev to the checkbox targeting, which helped shorten some of this code. I also added "*auto-stop*" functionality, meaning the loop will stop once it has finally cleared the list.

** **// UPDATE (08.20.14)**
I made a few changes to the code, to make it more user friendly. Other users may not be code-savvy, and others may simply prefer convenience. Therefore, I whipped up a couple buttons (start/stop) to control the usage; as well as address some "ASSERTION FAILED" exceptions/errors that were being thrown when attempted to run the script loop.. Enjoy!!

**In your address bar, type in the following address to to the meat of the history page.. It's normally loaded in an iframe, with the left-side menu loaded in another frame..**  // **

```
chrome://history-frame/
```

Next, load your Console Debugger/Viewer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
(For Mac users, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

You can also press <kbd>F12</kbd> and select the "**Console**" tab.

In the **Console Debugger/Viewer**, copy & paste the following code:

```
function removeItems() {
removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-selected');
overlayWindow = document.getElementById('overlay');
    //revision (07.28.15): Replaced the For Loop targeting the checkboxes, thanks to Denis Gorbachev via comments (02.19.15)
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), function(node) {node.checked = "checked"})
setTimeout(function () {
    if (removeButton.getAttribute("disabled") !== null) {
        removeButton.removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
    /* revision (08.20.14): no longer binding to that condition, button should no longer be disabled, so click! */
    if ((overlayWindow.hasAttribute("hidden")) && (overlayWindow.getAttribute("hidden") !== false)) {
        removeButton.click();
    }
    /* revision (08.20.14): new Interval, to check against the overlay DIV containing the confirmation "Remove" button */
    /* Attempting to click the button while the DIV's "hidden" attribute is in effect will cause FAILED ASSERTION */
    stopButton = setInterval(function () {
        if (overlayWindow.hasAttribute("hidden")) {
            if (overlayWindow.getAttribute("hidden") == "false") {
                hidden = false
            } else {
                hidden = true
            }
        } else {
            hidden = false
        }
        if (!hidden) {
            document.getElementById("alertOverlayOk").click();
            clearInterval(stopButton)
        }
    }, 250)
}, 250)
}
//revision (08.20.14): Lets build our buttons to control this so we no longer need the console
//stop button (08.20.14)
var stopButton = document.createElement('button');
stopButton.setAttribute('id', "stopButton");
stopButton.innerHTML = "Stop";
stopButton.style.background = "#800";
stopButton.style.color = "#fff";
stopButton.style.display = "none";
stopButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(window.clearAllFiltered);
    document.getElementById("stopButton").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("startButton").style.display = ""
};
//start button (08.20.14)
var startButton = document.createElement('button');
startButton.setAttribute('id', "startButton");
startButton.innerHTML = "Start";
startButton.style.background = "#090";
startButton.style.color = "#fff";
startButton.onclick = function () {
    window.clearAllFiltered = setInterval(function () {
/* revision (07.28.15): Stop the Loop automatically if there are no more items to remove */
        if(document.getElementById("results-header").innerText=="No search results found."){
            document.getElementById("stopButton").click();
            }
        if (document.getElementById("loading-spinner").getAttribute("hidden") !== null) {
            removeItems()
        }
    }, 250); //adjust Time Here (1500 [millisec] = 1.5sec)
    document.getElementById("stopButton").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("startButton").style.display = "none"
};
/* revision (08.20.14): Now we add our buttons, and we're ready to go! */
editingControls = document.getElementById('editing-controls');
editingControls.appendChild(stopButton);
editingControls.appendChild(startButton);
```

This removeItems function will select loop through all form inputs and check all checkboxes, enable the "Remove Selected Items" button and click it. After a half-second, it'll check if the "Are You Sure" prompt is displayed and, if so, click the "Yes/Remove" button automatically for you so that it will load a new list of items to do this process all over again..

The item is looped using the variable "clearAllFiltered", which is a setInterval loop, which is checking for the status of the "Loading" screen..

To start erasing your filtered history items, you can now click the green <kbd>**Start**</kbd> button.

** **// UPDATE (07.28.2015) It will now stop on ITS OWN.**

To stop the loop *manually*, you can now click the red <kbd>**Stop**</kbd> button. Simple as that!

Comment: Game changer! And fun to watch :)

Comment: this is not working ATM. The content is inside of in iframe and thus the button creation above fails

Comment: AhmadAssaf, 

I use this every 4 days or so per week, but at least once a week. I've been using it today 3 hours ago for 2 hours,. 
Please read the message _at the very top of these instructions_ , inside the UPDATE announcement. **It is the last sentence.** 

I address the source of that frame directly. You can't just use this from the history panel. You have to type that address in to access the source of the frame.

Comment: A simpler solution: `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), function(node) {node.checked = "checked"})`

Comment: Unexpected behaviour: this bought up two 'Start' buttons (until I clicked one and it changed to 'Stop', then removed *ALL* my history with no warning - I was expecting it to find duplicates in my history and remove them. Perhaps I should have read through it more carefully, but still… :-(

Comment: I was naive to think that this will use the text entered into the input box.. now all of my history is wiped, which is what I wanted to avoid. Just a note for future visitors: you actually have to click on the "Search" button, otherwise you lose all of your history.

Comment: @JacobCruz Is it possible somehow to keep only the last visitings of websites and delete duplicates of the websites from Google Chrome History by handling your code?

Answer (score 9):

1) Go to your history settings ( chrome://history/ )

2) In the top right hand corner will be a search bar with a 'Search History" button

3) Type in the sitename you want to remove from history, then click the button

4) Click the box on the first one, then scroll to the bottom of the page

5) Press and hold the Shift key, then click the last box (This will check all on that page)

6) Scroll back up and select the 'Remove Selected Items" Button

7) Repeat steps 4-6 until all your Youtube History is gone.

Hopefully Chrome will update this clear history feature, but for now this seems to be the fastest option

Answer (score 5):

Easy way is Shift+Delete.

For example when you type "you", "youtube.com" will be shown as selected in suggestions. Just click Shift+Delete. Then retype "you" and you will see no "youtube.com" in that list anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about getting rid of the suggested search/auto-completion... then removing specific items from your chrome://history won't do it (in my experience).  I want to fill in more detail to the answer [@LacOniC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4663265/laconic) gave.

[image: Chrome Auto-complete]

In the screenshot you can see I typed "ba" and Chrome is suggesting completion based on my browsing history (the items in green).

In my experience, removing specific items from your history will not remove them from showing up in this address bar auto-completion.

To quickly remove these auto complete items:

1. Start typing a few letters that generate the offending suggestion.
2. Use your keyboard's arrow keys to select the suggestion you don't like (selected item is highlighted blue in screenshot).
3. Press `shift+delete` on windows or `shift+fn+delete` on mac to remove the selected item.